# Xcode 7 Code Coverage reporting for multiple projects in a workspace

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-coverage

I have a workspace with 6 projects, 5 of these projects generate apps for the store, the other project is an example project which isn't really setup yet.  When I run the test scheme (which tests all projects) the code coverage report only shows the appdelegate.m and main.m for the example project.  There is no coverage data show within Xcode for any project.  The logs show that tests were run for every project and all passed.  Can anyone explain to me why Xcode would not be showing coverage data for any of the projects.

Comment: Did you enabled `coverage` for all targets in projects?

Comment: I had generate coverage report enabled in my schemes, but it turns out I also needed to enable coverage inside of the target as you said.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: For anyone wondering, inside of build settings set "Enable Code Coverage Support" to yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need check **Enable Code Coverage Support** for all targets that you want coverage reports on.